# Can we reverse Applicative of List?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative, scala-cats

[I'm reading about scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Applicative.html) and noticed that we can make a list of `Applicative`s to be an `Applicative` of `List`.

```
def sequenceA[F[_]: Applicative, A](list: List[F[A]]): F[List[A]] = list match {
         case Nil     => (Nil: List[A]).point[F]
         case x :: xs => (x |@| sequenceA(xs)) {_ :: _} 
       }
```

The question is can we do the opposite? Can we transform `F[List[A]]` to `List[F[A]]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible if the `F` in question is `Traversable`. The code you're showing is specialized for `List`, but in fact it holds for all `Traversable` functors.

This means, that for every `F` that's `Traversable` and any `G` that's `Applicative`, we can go from `F[G[A]]` to `G[F[A]]` with `sequence`.

`List` also has an `Applicative`, so we can use it as our `G`, whereas in your example `List` was used as the `F`, the `Traversable` functor.

An example where what you're asking works could be `Option`. Here's the original direction:

```
val x: List[Option[Int]] = ...
val y: Option[List[Int]] = x.sequence
```

and the other direction:

```
val a: Option[List[Int]] = ...
val b: List[Option[Int]] = a.sequence
```

We could also write another function specializing to `List`:

```
def sequenceT[F[_]: Traverse, A](list: F[List[A]]): List[F[A]] = ...
```